# Create full data frame from possible combinations of grouping variables

Tags: r, missing-data

I apologize if this has been asked before, but I could not find the answer I needed when there are three grouping variables.

I need to fill a dataframe with possible combinations of variables, but insert NAs for a non-grouping observation values when a combination does not appear. Say there is a dataframe with three grouping variables: Year, Geography, and Grouping:

```
Year <- rep(2008:2019,each=50)
Geography <- rep(1:60,each=10)
Grouping <- rep(1:4,each=150)
value <- seq(rnorm(600,mean=0,sd=1))
df=cbind(Year,Geography)
df=as.data.frame(cbind(df,value))
```

But the dataframe is missing some random observations like so:

```
df2=df[-c(15,60,150,510),]
```

How would one go about changing the dataframe back into a length of 600 (which is the length it would be if all possible combinations of three grouping variables were present), but inserting NAs where the value would be if the combinations were in the dataframe? Note that all unique observations for each grouping variable are present in the dataset at some point.

Comment: `merge( expand.grid( Year, Geography), df)`. Do note that using `cbind` on vectors gives you a character matrix rather than a dataframe if any of the vectors were character, and you probably forgot about `Grouping`. The construct `as.data.frame(cbind ...))` is an abomination that for some reason keeps popping up. Someone should track down the source of this zombie code and drive a stake through its heart. I also seriously doubt that the `value` vector is what you imagine it to be.

Comment: I see what I did... Sort of a newbie here. I appreciate the comment.